# Trouble scaling 9patch images evenly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, png, nine-patch

I'm attempting to make some simple 9patch PNG photos for using with `ImageButton` views, however they are not scaling correctly.  For example, here is the 9patch PNG image I'm using:

[image]

**However this is how it scales:**

[image]

**This is my XML for the buttons:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"  >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_challenge1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lockedbutton1"
    android:onClick="add1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_challenge2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lockedbutton1"
    android:onClick="add2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_challenge3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lockedbutton1"
    android:onClick="add3" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_challenge4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lockedbutton1"
    android:onClick="add4" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_challenge5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lockedbutton1"
    android:onClick="add5" />                          
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm really not sure why the images are scaling with the content (the lock) a lot further to the right than the left, as opposed to being stretched evenly and keeping the lock in the center.  Any ideas as to why this is happening?  Thanks a bunch of anybody could offer some help.

Comment: have you checked, that the image in your project is actually the one, that you expect it to be? Maybe there is more strech area on the left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the lock image out of the 9-patch, make a separate PNG with lock and define it with `android:src` instead. To center in button use `android:layout_gravity=center`.

Comment: Good suggestion, this should work. Thank you! However I'd still be curious to know why the image only seems to be scaling in one direction rather than evenly, or if that's even possible.